# Run program in cmd mode after building from Sublime Text 2

Tags: c++, c, mingw, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text 2 with MinGW as a build system to compile my c++ programs. I have the following build added to my Sublime:

```
{
    "cmd": ["mingw32-g++.exe", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file"],
    "path": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MinGWStudio\\MinGW\\bin\\"
}
```

Now I want to run the program that I've just compiled in a cmd window (not in the Sublime console) What should I add to that command ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A build system like the following will run your program in a new `cmd` window after you build it:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["mingw32-g++.exe", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file"],
    "path": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MinGWStudio\\MinGW\\bin\\",

    "variants": [

        {   
            "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name"],
            "shell": true,
            "name": "Run"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `"Run"` name has special significance, it means that when you select this build system as your default, hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> will compile your program, and then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> will execute it. `start` is the command to start running a separate process, `cmd` is short for `cmd.exe`, the Windows command line program, and the `/k` option keeps the resulting window open after your program exits so you can see its output, run additional commands, or what have you.

Comment: If you've having an issue where the code output still doesn't run, make sure you've got `cmd` instead of `shell_cmd`. Using the latter suppresses the output.

Answer (score 0):

For those trying this on MacOs (High Sierra) and Sublime 2, you might want to consider the next string in your build system:

```
{
    "cmd": ["make", "${file_base_name}"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "variants": [

        {   
            "cmd": ["/Applications/vice/x64sc.app/Contents/MacOS/x64sc $file_base_name"],
            "shell": true,
            "name": "Run"
        }
    ]   
}
```

This example will start Vice (the C64 emulator) installed in its specific location, which takes the file base name as an argument. Please note that I do not use "start", "cmd" or "/k".